# Bootstrap's Modal box - background doesn't fade out on show

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'm currently working on a C# MVC application. I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap's modal boxes as a 'popup' window. This has worked flawlessly in the past, but for some reason it doesn't right now. The result I get right now is shown below. Don't mind the blur, I did that.

Naturally the background is supposed to get grey, faded out like always, though for some reason it doesn't right now. I've basically copy pasted the code that works elsewhere and changed the values. I double and triple checked to make sure I didn't make a mistake somewhere, but I honestly can't see it.

[image: a busy cat]

I've pasted the relevant code below. JQuery gets loaded in the layout file. This is a partial view for the record

```
    <button id="btnAddNewSecureFolder" onclick="openTheCreateWindow()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-new-secFolder" class="btn btn-md btn-default giveMeSomeSpace leaveMeAlone">Add a secure folder</button>

    @*<button onclick="openTheCreateWindow()" class="btn btn-md btn-default giveMeSomeSpace leaveMeAlone" id="btnAddNewSecureFolder">
        Add a secure folder
    </button>*@


    <div class="modal" id="modal-new-secFolder" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-new-secFolder" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close cancel" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add a new secure folder</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @Html.Partial("CreateNewSecureFolder")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
    function openTheCreateWindow() {
        $('#modal-new-secFolder').modal('show');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I would guess something in your CSS is hiding it...[your code as is works fine](http://www.bootply.com/pw5nLDWRFC). Check to be sure your bootstrap css and js versions match, or better yet be sure they're current.

Comment: the whole thing already works elsewhere with basically the exact same code, so I doubt it's that. This is the first time I'm working with parent/partial views though, so I guess it's something to do with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in Chrome Developer Tools if

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

exists right before closing `</body>` tag.

Styles for this div:

[image]

Also try to remove

```
aria-hidden="true"
```

attribute from your modal dialog.

Comment: when I click on the Create button, there appears a '<div class="modal-backdrop  in"></div>' line right before a '<body>' tag. No fade though. Also I did notice there are 2 <body> tags. The second one is in an iFrame, one I use elsewhere, which is not visible to the user, nor used for the record. Though it's still in the code. Maybe it confuses Bootstrap

Comment: Probably. What about styles? Do you have the same styles? And what about aria-hidden attribute?

Try to add "fade" class manually to class attribute.

Comment: Just tried removing the iFrame that put an extra <body> tag in the code. It doesn't help though. I still get no fade.

Comment: Have you tried put "fade" manually in Chrome Developer Tools to class attribute of this div right above closing </body> tag? Does it work?

Comment: I added fade in the class of that <div>  tag like you asked and pressed enter, but nothing happens. Gonna try to remove the aria-hidden attribute in code. I really don't understand, since this whole thing works in plenty of other views. Think it might have something to do with parent/partial views.

Comment: Just tried removing aria-hidden attribute, but that doesn't do anything either

Comment: Okay, seems like you don't have definitions for fade class. It makes sense. Now try to load bootstrap from CDN. Three files from "Bootstrap CDN" section from here:

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Add them to head section of your webpage. And try to: 1) reload the page 2) if doesn't work - add "fade" class 3) if doesn't work - remove aria-hidden attribute.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, but I got it working! I added the pair of .css links from Bootstrap's page and that gave me some glorious fade! Thank you so much!